# Stack Exchange for Popular Music and Music Videos

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Is there a Stack Exchange where questions can be asked regarding musical artists, music videos, etc?

For example, if someone was wondering about how a band formed, which artists hail from a certain country, the meaning of lyrics, mentions of a town in songs, etc.

This question comes from the fact that I have a music video where it seems like the artist's voice is cut out at certain times and I was wondering what the missing words were.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Music Fans](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/) is now in Beta! What is on and off-topic is still being determined; you can probably ask your question there now though. See the Music Fans Meta, there is a question on that topic there: [Are questions about music videos on topic?](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155/are-questions-about-music-videos-on-topic)

---

When this question was asked, there was no such site **yet**. There was a [Area51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61574/music-fans) however that **may** accept your music video question, once started:

> #### Music Fans
>
> Proposed Q&A site for music listening enthusiasts, music historians, and members of the music press corps to ask questions regarding (known) interpretations of songs, historical influences of bands, and the music industry (including production) in general

[Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) is where new sites are proposed, initial communities form and initial scope is determined. When this question was asked, the the *Music Fans* site was in the *commitment* phase, where it tries to gain enough committed members to help bootstrap the site. It gained enough committed members to open in private beta, and has now moved to public beta. It'll hopefully gain enough momentum to graduate to a permanent member of the Stack Exchange network.