# Where should I ask an "identify-this-music-video-clip" question?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I vaguely remember a video clip from a decade or so.. I need help from community to identify it (the band and the song).

Where should I ask for help ?

Comment: Bottom line: no such site, and since there are already sites for music fans and music in general, very low chance of yet another site for identifying music/clips/etc.

Comment: Thanks @ShadowWizard, you may want to put it as an answer :)

Comment: "...these questions aren’t educational in any way, because there’s no way to learn about the process of discovery. A particular community member, by virtue of their experience in the field, just happens to be able to take the limited information you remembered and fill in enough of the blanks to guess the correct answer... guessing game questions do not meet our goal of making the Internet better." (http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game) -- I think it'd be difficult to find a SE site that will prefer to deviate from this guidance...

Comment: ...maybe [not quite 100% impossible](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252350/165773) but difficult

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a SE site to ask "what is this song"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243092/282094) https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238920/282094  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300729/282094

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that there is already a music site, so you should get it on-topic there, since it [isn't at the moment](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34/identify-this-song-genre-artist-on-topic) (thanks [Shadow Wizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/152859/shadow-wizard) for commenting [that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252376/where-should-i-ask-an-identify-this-music-video-clip-question#comment824232_252376)) (ask on their meta, not likely to happen), or get a new site (not likely too due to the user base you need).

In my opinion you can describe a movie easier than a piece of music, so that might be a reason that is can be on-topic on Movie.SE and not on Music Fans, I think you don't have any chance here.

Comment: bbb... but why: http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-movie ?

Comment: Well, [identify-this-movie](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-movie) is very popular on http://movies.stackexchange.com/ and while not making excellent questions, is still useful to many people and considered on topic there. [Exhibit A](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/32/identify-this-movie-questions) (old, but still relevant), [Exhibit B](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1671/extend-the-policy-for-deleting-inactive-identification-questions) (original way to keep the site cleaner). So all in all, I do not agree with your general idea.

Comment: No -1 because the final conclusion is correct, no site for identify-this-song, but for other reasons than you mention.

Comment: Answer. Maybe "reasons" is not the correct word, more like your general idea that "identify-this-thing" is off topic for whole Stack Exchange. Each site set its own rules, to some extent of course. :)

Comment: Just to keep it clear, I not talk about "identify-this-song" (for me describe a piece of music is just not possible) but more "identify-this-video-clip"

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yet, M&TV thought hard to get at least some ID-things thrown out, and music video and commercial identification belong to that. So there really doesn't seem to be a place for this kind of question.

Answer (score 3):

Music video identification has been [ruled off-topic](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1280/49) on [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/), too. So together with *Patrick*'s answer, I don't think there is a valid place for you to ask this question at the moment.