# Do we have a community for identifying the title of a music or tune?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a tune that keeps on playing on my mind but can't find the exact music on YouTube. Do we have a community here in the Stack Exchange Network for such inquiries?

Comment: Does it go "dum dum dum dee da dum de da dum"?

Comment: I think that's Disturbia... the music I am searching is somewhat around 80s or early 90s.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where should I ask an "identify-this-music-video-clip" question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252376/where-should-i-ask-an-identify-this-music-video-clip-question)

Answer (score 5):

I don't think we do. But more importantly, **can you ask the question in such a way that music experts could give an objectively correct answer?** I believe there is no site for this because that's usually not possible.

I think the only way you could make such a question answerable is if you remembered the lyrics well enough to write them down (in which case you can just Google those lyrics) or if you remember a sufficiently distinctive part of the melody so well that you can transcribe it to sheet music (which seems unlikely), or if you remember a very specific place where it was used (e.g., background music from a specific Star Trek episode might be okay here, if the answer is not trivially Google-able).

Though [story-identification](/questions/tagged/story-identification) does pretty well on SciFi.SE, on some stackexchange sites (Arqade and Anime.SE for instance), identification questions are seen as a nuisance or a blight because a lot of them are so vague that the only way to answer them correctly is to read OP's mind, and it's likely the same would be true of most song identification questions.

Comment: I remember the melody, and have even ascribed it as a piano-melody and use tune search websites.  But the sites were unsuccessful in identifying the correct song.

Comment: @BlueDeeper If tune-searches didn't do it I doubt there's much else we could do to help, unless there was some context like it appearing in a specific video game or movie or TV show or something. It looks like even the "MusicFans" beta SE [strongly feels music-identification shoud be off-topic](http://meta.musicfans.stackexchange.com/a/37), so you're probably out of luck.

Comment: @Ixrec Well, on the other hand [musicfans.se] seems to be overthinking this approach recently (without a proper meta-rediscussion, though) in favour of accepting ID questions to gather more momentum (since we all know ID questions bring the most dedicated users anyway ;-)).

Comment: @TARS Cool, maybe this OP's question could provide a useful sample for when the rediscussion becomes public. However, I though ID questions were notorious for bringing primarily "drive-by" users that don't stick around (or was that meant as sarcasm?).

Comment: *"or was that meant as sarcasm?"* - Yeah, as intended by the *";-)"*. Your assessment about the prevalent nature of those users in general is absolutely reasonable. They are basically the media sites' equivalent of SO's *"gimme teh codez"* people. But anyway, I guess we're digressing from the topic. ;-)

Comment: I guess you could post a link to a recording of you humming it.

Comment: @JasonC Reminds me of Arqade's "audiovisual artifact" rule.

Comment: @Ixrec Fair point, but "what is this movie" is allowed on Movies.SE as well.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there no such site at the moment. However, Area 51 has a proposal named [Song Identification and Interpretation](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/87078/song-identification-and-interpretation) which seems to be what you're looking for.

You can follow the proposal and help it reach beta status by contributing new example questions and upvoting existing ones.

Comment: WUT? Interesting, maybe this could even be broadened to Movie and TV-Show identification then. And maybe the guys over on [anime.se] are interested in having a dump for ID, too? Maybe even the people at [scifi.se], though, they seem much more content with the occasional ID question.

Comment: Though, song interpretation seems perfectly on-topic on [musicfans.se] already.

Comment: @Christian Rau I'll check on the Music Fans you mentioned.