# Where to ask question about obscure old vinyl record?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want to locate an obscure old LP vinyl record from the 70's and have been unable to despite a lot of searching. Which Stack Exchange site is best?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go for [**Music Fans**](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/), instead of [Music Practice & Theory](https://music.stackexchange.com) as suggested in the other answer. The reason is that most identification requests are [off-topic](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2662/19800) on Music Stack Exchange.

Music Fans, on the other hand, has a better record (pun intended) for [identify this song](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-song) questions, and also a few questions asking to [identify this album](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-album).

From their [help center](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Please note that ID questions (What is the name of this song/band/etc?) are currently considered on-topic, provided that the question contains sufficient detail to make the identification possible. A link to an actual recording is best, but if one is not available, clear, specific and plentiful details including language, genre, style, lyrics, etc may be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are looking for [LP_record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LP_record) the [Music Stack Exchange](https://music.stackexchange.com) 
might be the right place.

Music Q&A Examples:

- [Record Label Instrumentals](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/24907/record-label-instrumentals/24912#24912)
- [What's the theory behind the “80s” sound of a song?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/11429/whats-the-theory-behind-the-80s-sound-of-a-song/16164#16164)

Comment: I was worried that might be too general, or that a trivia or antiques stackexchange might be preferable. I'll wait for more suggestions and if nothing else is suggested I'll try there. Thanks.